# Run Macro Every 2 hours Only if previous run is complete

Tags: vba, excel, scheduled-tasks

I've set a macro to run every 2 hours by using:

```
Application.OnTime (TimeSerial(6, 0, 0)), "AutoUpdate"
```

However there is an issue sometimes as occasionally the macro will spill over 2 hours and try to run again whilst the previous macro is still running, causing it to crash. Does anybody know of a way to say "if the previous "AutoUpdate" is still running then do not run the "AutoUpdate" again?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a global variable of type Boolean:

```
Dim gRunning as Boolean
```

In your sub, add the following code:

```
If gRunning = True Then
  Exit Sub
End If

gRunning = True 

[...]

gRunning = False
```